# Типы предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Конфет мне не полагается. Это предложение односоставное?

Answer (score 3):

Это односоставное безличное предложение.

Конфеты мне не полагаются - это двусоставное предложение, глагол в форме пассивного залога.
Думаю, что безличное предложение из него не построишь. Например, конфета мне не полагается - это единственное число, а в безличных предложения используются только две формы: не полагаются и не полагалось.

По-моему, такие ситуации часто встречаются в языке, например: следы не видны - не видно следов. У нас есть определенное содержание, и есть две формы для выражения этого содержания. Соответственно, автор может выбрать подходящую. Однако только с первого взгляда две формы абсолютно похожи, поэтому попробуем найти различие.

(1)Следы не видны, но, может быть, они существуют? (2)Не видно следов -  автор полагает, что, скорее всего, их вовсе нет.

(1) Конфет (Р.п.) мне не полагается: что касается конфет (в отличие от других сладостей), то они мне не полагаются. 
(2) Конфеты (И.п.)мне не полагаются: именно эти конфеты, которые сейчас делят, мне не полагаются.

Впрочем, всё это "авторские" рассуждения - возможно, лично вы можете объяснить разницу по-другому. Или вам оба варианта покажутся абсолютно одинаковыми - это тоже ваше авторское мнение.

Comment: А если так:конфеты мне не полагаются.

Comment: Ведь никакой разницы. А Получается двусоставное.

Comment: По смыслу - да.Разница только в грамматике: в одном случае нет подлежащего, а во втором есть.